# How Can I get Material UI Dialog To Work With React useEffect()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to fetch data from an API and update using form inside material UI dialog. But I have
tried all I could and the dialog will will not open.

It opens only when I comment out the line like below. Can someone help figure out what the issue is?
Why the dialog will not open until I comment out the line below.

```
const handleOpen = () => {
    setValues({ open: true });
    //mapUserData(credentials)
};
```

This is my code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { editProfile } from '../../store/actions/userActions';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import useStyle from './style'
import Input from '../forms/controls/Input'
import { useForm } from '../../hooks/useForm/useForm'
import Modal from 'react-modal';

//MUI Components
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

const EditProfile = () => {
    const { handleChange, values, setValues } = useForm({
        firstName: '', lastName: '', handle: '',
        open: false
    })

    const { credentials } = useSelector((state) => state.users);
    const classes = useStyle()

    const mapUserData = (data) => {
        setValues({
            firstName: data?.firstName ? data?.firstName : '',
            lastName: data?.lastName ? data?.lastName : '',
            handle: data?.handle ? data?.handle : '',
        });
    }

    const handleOpen = () => {
        setValues({ open: true });
        mapUserData(credentials)
    };


    const handleClose = () => {
        setValues({ open: false });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        mapUserData(credentials)
    }, []);

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        const profile = {
            firstName: profile?.firstName,
            lastName: profile?.lastName,
            handle: profile?.handle
        }

        editProfile(profile)
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <IconButton onClick={handleOpen}>
                <Tooltip title="Edit Profile" placement="top">
                    <EditIcon fontSize="small" color="inherit" className={classes.edit} />
                </Tooltip>

            </IconButton>

            <Dialog
                open={values?.open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                fullWidth
                maxWidth="sm"
            >
                <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Edit Profile</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <form>
                        <Input
                            name="firstName"
                            value={values?.firstName}
                            type="text"
                            autoFocus={true}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <Input
                            name="lastName"
                            value={values?.lastName}
                            type="text"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <Input
                            name="handle"
                            value={values?.handle}
                            type="text"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                    </form>
                </DialogContent>

                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                        Cancel
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={handleSubmit} color="primary">
                        Save
                    </Button>
                </DialogActions>

            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Try just putting {open} in the open prop of the dialog? I do not see what part you’re commenting out to make it work. Wait I see it, why would put that there as a prop anyway?

Comment: It is not a prop. the commented out part is a call to a function that sets the state